# Windows Phone 8 + Autofac constructor injection

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have a running MVC project where the Autofac is used. Now I'm writing the Windows Phone 8 app, so I'd like to use the Autofac as well.

In the MVC app I register types as this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<MailRepository>().As<IMailRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

In the controller I just call it as this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IMailRepository _mailRepository;

    public HomeController(IMailRepository mailRepository)
    {
        this._mailRepository = mailRepository;
    } 

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Use this._mailRepository here
    }
}
```

So as easy as possible.

Now I'm just wondering how to resolve the container in WP8 app (exactly like this in MVC: *DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));*)
I have found anything neither in the official documentation nor on Google.
I don't want to call resolve everytime I need the object.

Thank you.

**Edit:**
Ok, now I understand it's more about WP8 than about Autofac. In Windows Phone 8 I'm missing the place how to inject the dependency, as in the MVC DependencyResolver does..

**EDIT 2:**
Ok, I have the reason now. The problem is, that pages are navigated to by the *Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame.Navigate(Type, string)* method which is creating the pages itself and needs the parameterless contstructor.
I'm afraiding there is no way how to inject the constructor, because the method is accepting the type of page, not the instance of object that could be resolved.

**I can't believe Microsoft does not offer any option for this!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone does not offer a DI container, neither does MVC for that matter.

You need to use a third party library. If you use a MVVM toolkit like Caliburn.Micro, it contains a simple DI container (you can also use Ninject with it and maybe even Autofac) and then you can use constructor injection in your ViewModels the same way you use it in Controllers in MVC.

Comment: I'm using the Autofac, but I don't want to use the injection in the constructor of ViewModels, but I want to inject the ViewModel into the constructor of View. And that is the problem.

Comment: I do not get it, you want to have access to the ViewModel in the View's code behind file? Why? There is no need for this with MVVM

Comment: Because I need to pass somehow the ViewModel to the View. When I click to the Save button, I call the method on ViewModel...etc.
Or maybe I just don't get the concept right... I'm from pure MVC world, I've read this article about MVVM and I can see it here as well (calling of the VM in the V):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg521153(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: no need to pass ViewModel for your use case. I recommend you read this series that explains everything http://wp.qmatteoq.com/first-steps-with-caliburn-micro-in-windows-phone-8-the-complete-series/

Comment: care to accept the answer? it basically got you on the right track